# Изменение Фона диалога на белый цвет

Tags: java, android

в  манифесте использую тему 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog
текст отображается в черном окне диалога ,надо изменить цвет окна на белый но как??
Также приму ответы по поводу добавления диалоговых окон любые советы ценный 
П.С спасибо

Comment: на ваш вопрос, можно дать много ответов. попробуйте данный стиль Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog

Comment: щас попробуем)))Если  вам не лень можете меня удивить разнообразием)))я готто выслушать)

Comment: Попробуйте вот эту библиотку - с ней удобнее диалоги делать чем через стандартное решение - https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

Comment: Спасибо FppcomLight не поддержиается)а насчет материальных они не поддержиают апи  ниже 21 это создаст некий дискомфорт )нужна альтернатиа

Comment: подтягивать lib, чтоб изменить цвет диалога), не думаю что это практично) существует +100500 способов это элегантно сделать в студии

Comment: ххааа)))лан покапаюсь дальше)

Comment: Ну дай еще один элегантный способ)и завоюй мое сердце)))

Comment: хах, юмор я люблю, ок

Answer (score 1):

```
Попробуйте так:
<style name="AppDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <!-- ... -->
    <item name="@android:background">@android:color/background_light</item>
    <item name="@android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Не думаю у меня материал тема